# Halting a stage rollout not working using Fastlane - Android

Tags: android, fastlane, fastlane-supply

I have used the following code to halt a stage rollout release but unfortunately it's not working

```
desc "halt stage rollout on playstore"
lane :halt_deployment do
  upload_to_play_store(
    track: 'beta',
    release_status: 'halted',
    version_code: '101110',
    track_promote_release_status: 'halted',
    skip_upload_aab: true,
    skip_upload_apk: true,
    skip_upload_metadata: true,
    skip_upload_images: true,
    skip_upload_screenshots: true,
    skip_upload_changelogs: true,
    changes_not_sent_for_review: true
  )
end
```

It keeps giving this error

[!] No local metadata, apks, aab, or track to promote were found, make sure to run fastlane supply init to setup supply

Can anybody help with it . Have tried many things but didn't work

Tried running fastlane supply init but it didn't do the work too.

Comment: you have to define: `track_promote_to: 'beta'`